# Issue in simple neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

I tried below code in tensorflow with different variations for a simple regression problem. I have synthesized data as `y=10.0*x`. One input and one outcome variable. But tensorflow is giving me a loss of ~2000 to ~200000. I am using MSE as the loss function. Also tried relu activations as well, without any use.

1. What should be the appropriate model for such a [simple] regression problem?
2. What should the model be for problem like `y=x^3`?

```
def PolynomialModel():
    inp = layers.Input((1))
    l=layers.Dense(16, activation='tanh')(inp)
    l=layers.Dense(8, activation='tanh')(l)
    l=layers.Dropout(.5)(l)
    l=layers.Dense(4, activation='tanh')(l)
    l=layers.Dropout(.5)(l)
    output=layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh')(l)
    return models.Model(inp,output)
```

Comment: Why do you use `activation='tanh'` and not `'linear'` for `y=10.0*x`?

Comment: `Dropout(.5)` seems like a very high value for 4 neurons. Doesn't that mean that there will be all zero activations with probability 1/16?

Comment: Tried with no dropouts as well. Also tried with a single Dense layer, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you don't need hidden layers but an input of the size of the polynomial degree + 1. Check the documentation of [`PolynomialFeatures`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) from `sklearn` for more information.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, optimizers, activations

def PolynomialModel(degree):
    inp = layers.Input((degree+1))
    out = layers.Dense(1)(inp)  # activation='linear'
    return models.Model(inp, out)

# Suppose you want to fit a polynomial function of degree 3
degree = 3
model = PolynomialModel(degree)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',  optimizer=optimizers.Adam(0.1))

# You need an input vector of degree+1 (here: x**0, x**1, x**2 and x**3)
x = tf.linspace(-20, 20, 1000)
X = tf.transpose(tf.convert_to_tensor([x**p for p in range(degree+1)]))
y = x**3

model.fit(X, y, epochs=200)
model.predict([[4**0, 4**1, 4**2, 4**3]])
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/200
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 974us/step - loss: 891936.5000
Epoch 2/200
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 945us/step - loss: 25650.7812
Epoch 3/200
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 897us/step - loss: 1188.4584
Epoch 4/200
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 75.3480
Epoch 5/200
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 21.2651
...
Epoch 196/200
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2130e-11
Epoch 197/200
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.5810e-11
Epoch 198/200
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2358e-11
Epoch 199/200
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2775e-11
Epoch 200/200
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.4443e-11
```

Test:

```
>>> model.predict([[4**0, 4**1, 4**2, 4**3]])
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 63ms/step
array([[64.]], dtype=float32)

>>> model.predict([[3**0, 3**1, 3**2, 3**3]])
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 51ms/step
array([[27.000002]], dtype=float32)

>>> model.summary()
Model: "PolynomialRegressor"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 Input (InputLayer)          [(None, 4)]               0         
                                                                 
 Output (Dense)              (None, 1)                 5         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 5 (20.00 Byte)
Trainable params: 5 (20.00 Byte)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
```

Note: `x**0` is not really necessary (only ones...) but I want the same behavior than `PolynomialFeatures`. So you can also consider if your degree is 3, the input size is 3 (and not 4).

Comment: Should have used linear activations and some more epochs.

Comment: @user1288043. Exactly. If you use some hidden layers, you need more epochs to minimize the loss. For a regression, the output layer should be linear.